# How to debug custom keyboard in android?

Tags: android, keyboard, preferences

I have a legacy keyboard app for a legacy software application that unfortunately needs to be fixed.  I am running into a lot of problems just debugging it.

I'm stumped at trying to find a way to get into the guts of this app through the debugger, maybe create a stub project or test harness?

Here is the onCreate:

```
public class InputLanguageSelection extends PreferenceActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    // addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.language_prefs);
    // Get the settings preferences
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    mAvailableLanguages = getUniqueLocales();
    String selectedLanguagePref = sp.getString(LatinIME.PREF_SELECTED_LANGUAGES, "");
    Log.i(TAG, "selected languages: " + selectedLanguagePref);
    String[] languageList = selectedLanguagePref.split(",");

    // Compatibility hack for v1.22 and older - if a selected language 5-code isn't
    // found in the current list of available languages, try adding the 2-letter
    // language code. For example, "en_US" is no longer listed, so use "en" instead.
    Set<String> availableLanguages = new HashSet<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < mAvailableLanguages.size(); i++) {
        Locale locale = mAvailableLanguages.get(i).locale;
        availableLanguages.add(get5Code(locale));
    }
    Set<String> languageSelections = new HashSet<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < languageList.length; ++i) {
        String spec = languageList[i];
        if (availableLanguages.contains(spec)) {
            languageSelections.add(spec);
        } else if (spec.length() > 2) {
            String lang = spec.substring(0, 2);
            if (availableLanguages.contains(lang))
                languageSelections.add(lang);
        }
    }

    parent = getPreferenceScreen(); 

    for (int i = 0; i < mAvailableLanguages.size(); i++) {
        CheckBoxPreference pref = new CheckBoxPreference(this);
        Locale locale = mAvailableLanguages.get(i).locale;
        pref.setTitle(mAvailableLanguages.get(i).label + " [" + locale.toString() + "]");
        String fivecode = get5Code(locale);
        String language = locale.getLanguage();
        boolean checked = languageSelections.contains(fivecode);
        pref.setChecked(checked);
        boolean has4Row = arrayContains(KBD_4_ROW, fivecode) || arrayContains(KBD_4_ROW, language);
        boolean has5Row = arrayContains(KBD_5_ROW, fivecode) || arrayContains(KBD_5_ROW, language);
        List<String> summaries = new ArrayList<String>(3);
        if (has5Row)
            summaries.add("5-row");
        if (has4Row)
            summaries.add("4-row");
        // if (hasDictionary(locale)) {
        // summaries.add(getResources().getString(R.string.has_dictionary));
        // }
        if (!summaries.isEmpty()) {
            StringBuilder summary = new StringBuilder();
            for (int j = 0; j < summaries.size(); ++j) {
                if (j > 0)
                    summary.append(", ");
                summary.append(summaries.get(j));
            }
            pref.setSummary(summary.toString());
        }
        parent.addPreference(pref); 
    }

    }
```

Manifest (I had to add the launcher to the app to get it to launch in the debugger.  Commented out lines are what's in the release version):

```
    <activity
        android:name="InputLanguageSelection" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <!--<action android:name="com.assistek.util.keyboard.INPUT_LANGUAGE_SELECTION" />  -->
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <!--  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> -->
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I found this code for debugging a custom keyboard, but I still am unable to debug: [Here for debugging a service](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-debug-service) but I think I will need to somehow simulate keyboard input.